# CUDA: Confused as to why this test program doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: cuda

I've got a CUDA test program which is supposed to invert the RGB values of an image. On my system at least, this is producing an output image, but it is completely transparent.

Here's CudaLodepng.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "lodepng.h"


__global__
void NegativeFilter(unsigned char *inputImage, unsigned char *outputImage)
{

    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    int t;

    int threadIndex = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    int pixel = threadIndex * 4;

    printf("uid = %d\n", pixel);

    r = inputImage[pixel];
    g = inputImage[pixel+1];
    b = inputImage[pixel+2];
    t = inputImage[pixel+3];

    outputImage[pixel] = 255-r;
    outputImage[pixel+1] = 255-g;
    outputImage[pixel+2] = 255-b;
    outputImage[pixel+3] = t;

}


int main(int argc, char ** argv){

  unsigned int errorDecode;
  unsigned char* cpuImage;
  unsigned int width, height;
  
  char *filename = argv[1];
  char *newFilename = argv[2];

  errorDecode = lodepng_decode32_file(&cpuImage, &width, &height, filename);
  if(errorDecode){
    printf("error %u: %s\n", errorDecode, lodepng_error_text(errorDecode));
  }
  
  int arraySize = width*height*4;
  int memorySize = arraySize * sizeof(unsigned char);
  
  unsigned char *cpuOutImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(memorySize);
  
  unsigned char* gpuInput;
  unsigned char* gpuOutput;
  
  cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuInput, memorySize);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuOutput, memorySize);
  
  cudaMemcpy(gpuInput, cpuImage, memorySize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  
  NegativeFilter<<<1, width * height>>>(gpuInput, gpuOutput);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  cudaMemcpy(cpuOutImage, gpuOutput, memorySize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  
  unsigned int errorEncode = lodepng_encode32_file(newFilename, cpuOutImage, width, height);
  if(errorEncode) {
  printf("error %u: %s\n", errorEncode, lodepng_error_text(errorEncode));
  }

  cudaFree(gpuInput);
  cudaFree(gpuOutput);

  free(cpuImage);
  free(cpuOutImage);

}
```

A couple of other files are required for this to compile: `lodepng.h` and `lodepng.cpp`.

You can obtain them here: https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng

Finally, to compile and run:

```
nvcc CudaLodepng.cu lodepng.cpp
./a.out image.png imageout.png
```

If you don't want to bother downloading loadpng and running this code on a file, you might be able to spot the issue in the code itself. I've looked for an hour or so and can't figure it out.

I'm not new to CUDA but it's been about 5 years since I've done any, so this somewhat took me by surprise when it didn't appear to do anything.

(It compiles and runs fine by the way, but the output is just a transparent image on my system. I've been testing it with a 4x4 test image containing 4 color squares. You could knock the same thing up with gimp. I will attach the test image below but I have no idea if the data will transfer correctly. It's a 32 bit png, supposedly rgba format.)

Look for the really tiny image here

VVVVVV

[image: test image]

^^^^^^

Comment: run your code with `cuda-memcheck`, like this: `cuda-memcheck ./a.out image.png imageout.png`  and if it reports any errors, edit that output into your question.

Comment: No memcheck errors, I've realized what is wrong. See answer. (It's unrelated to the code.)

Answer (score 1):

Totally unrelated to the code above: The issue is I am on a linux laptop with a discrete and embedded GPU.

```
optirun ./a.out
```

is required to exec CUDA code on the Nvidia GPU.

I would have deleted the question, however there might be someone else on a Linux system with a similar configuration, and reading this answer might prevent them from wasting several hours going back and fourth trying to find a solution to a problem which doesn't exist. (aka in the code)